# How to update data with Hibernate and Spring JPA in Spring MVC

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

First I'm just a beginner who like to learn Spring framework. I'm creating Simple online domestic flight reservation system using `Spring MVC` with `Hibernate` and `Spring JPA`. This problem is raised when I'm going to update the name, email and contact no of registered users.

my-profile.jsp (Link for update-user.jsp)

```
<a href='<spring:url value="/account/my-profile/${user.id}.html"/>'>
    <button type="button">My Profile</button>
</a>
```

update-user.jsp

```
<form:form modelAttribute="userUpdate" method="POST" cssClass="userValidation" >


  <div>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <div>
      <form:input path="name" name="name"/>
      <form:errors path="name"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <form:input path="email" name="email"/>
      <form:errors path="email"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="contactNum">Contact No</label>
    <div>
      <form:input path="contactNum" name="contactNum"/>
      <form:errors path="contactNum"/>
    </div>
  </div>

</form:form>
```

UserController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/account/my-profile/{id}", method={RequestMethod.POST})
public String showProfile(@PathVariable int id, ModelMap model, 
                          @Valid @ModelAttribute("userUpdate") User user,
                          @ModelAttribute("user") User user2, 
                          BindingResult result,Authentication authentication){

    if(result.hasErrors()){
        return "my-profile";
    }

    String name = authentication.getName();
    User user3 = userService.findOne(name);
    userService.save(user3);

    return "redirect://flightInfos/booknow/payments.html?success=true";
}
```

UserService.java

```
public void save(User user) {
    user.setEnabled(true);
    BCryptPasswordEncoder encoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    user.setPassword(encoder.encode(user.getPassword()));

    List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<Role>();
    roles.add(roleRepository.findByName("ROLE_USER"));
    user.setRoles(roles);
    userRepository.save(user);      
}

public User findOne(String name) {
    return userRepository.findByName(name);
}
```

UserRepository.java

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
    User findByName(String name);
}
```

When I run this, no error is there and following `sql` statement is shown in console.

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_4_, user0_.contactNum as contactN2_4_, user0_.email as email3_4_, user0_.enabled as enabled4_4_, user0_.name as name5_4_, user0_.password as password6_4_, user0_.userId as userId7_4_ from myUser user0_ where user0_.name is null
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_4_, user0_.contactNum as contactN2_4_, user0_.email as email3_4_, user0_.enabled as enabled4_4_, user0_.name as name5_4_, user0_.password as password6_4_, user0_.userId as userId7_4_ from myUser user0_ where user0_.email is null
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_4_, user0_.contactNum as contactN2_4_, user0_.email as email3_4_, user0_.enabled as enabled4_4_, user0_.name as name5_4_, user0_.password as password6_4_, user0_.userId as userId7_4_ from myUser user0_ where user0_.name=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_4_, user0_.contactNum as contactN2_4_, user0_.email as email3_4_, user0_.enabled as enabled4_4_, user0_.name as name5_4_, user0_.password as password6_4_, user0_.userId as userId7_4_ from myUser user0_ where user0_.email=?
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_4_, user0_.contactNum as contactN2_4_, user0_.email as email3_4_, user0_.enabled as enabled4_4_, user0_.name as name5_4_, user0_.password as password6_4_, user0_.userId as userId7_4_ from myUser user0_ where user0_.name=?
Hibernate: select role0_.id as id1_3_, role0_.name as name2_3_ from Role role0_ where role0_.name=?
Hibernate: update myUser set contactNum=?, email=?, enabled=?, name=?, password=?, userId=? where id=?
Hibernate: delete from myUser_Role where users_id=?
Hibernate: insert into myUser_Role (users_id, roles_id) values (?, ?)
```

When I run this program, no change is happened in the database. And also I can't log using new credentials or using previous credentials.

I appreciate your help to find out this case. I need to update existing user. His name, email and contact no. What I can do to solve this matter ?

`Role` entity

```
@Entity
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy="roles")
    private List<User> users;

    getters and setters
```

`User` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "myUser")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
private String userId;

@Size(min=4, message="Name must be at least 4 characters.")
@UniqueUsername(message="Username exists")
@Column(unique=true)
private String name;

@Size(min=5, message="Password must be at least 5 characters.")
private String password;

@Size(min=1, message="Invalid email")
@Email(message="Invalid email")
@UniqueEmail(message="Email exists")
private String email;
private String contactNum;  
private Boolean enabled;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable
private List<Role> roles;

getters & setters
```

Comment: Don't you need a commit in there somewhere? Where's the concrete implementation for your UserRepository?

Comment: @Mark Sorry I'm really new to `Spring`, so I can't catch what you said. That is my `UserRepository` and that interface has been extended to `JpaRepository` Is there anything that I need to do ?

Comment: You **don't** need to implement `UserRepository` since you are using Spring Data JPA.

Comment: I would first suggest that you enable parameter logging as well as the query logging so you can get a clear view of what's going on. Check out [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-configure-logging-in-hibernate-logback/). More specifically for logback you need to add `<logger name="org.hibernate" level="DEBUG" />`

Comment: Could you please post the Role and User entitites?

Comment: Thank you @geoand I'l set logging. Then without implementing `UserRepository` how can I use queries like `findByName` ? Is there any alternative way ?

Comment: You do need the interface `UserRepository` (like you have), but you don't need an implementation of it (because Spring Data creates the implementation for you).

Comment: I added them @LucaPutzu

Comment: Thanks for the detail @geoand I referred (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mH2jx2RCu7o&list=PLmcxdcWPhFqMq2BctGktOcIJKUw23wJeh) by Jiri Pinkas He has edited `UserRepository` and also `RoleRepository` as I did. That is why I used it in that way. So then how can I use `findByname` like queries ?

Comment: Queries like `findByname` should work just fine with your current setup

Comment: Your logs seems just fine... I'd try to annotate your UserService.save method as @Transactional... just in case ;)

Comment: @LucaPutzu I've already annotated them as `@Transactional`

Comment: I think I need to look more about `Spring JPA` @geoand I searched a lot to find out any answer for my question. Thank you so much for your advice.

Comment: Problem solved @geoand and also I added logging as you said, it is really usable. Thank you so much :)

Comment: @RYJ You're welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where are you doing update? In your controller you are just getting user from db and saving it right after.

`User user3 = userService.findOne(name);
 userService.save(user3);`

You shoud do update user3 with new data. 
I would do it like this.

`User user3 = userService.findOne(name);
updateUser(user3, user);
userService.save(user3);`

updateUser method:

`private void updateUser(oldUser, newUser){
     oldUser.setName(newUser.getName());
     oldUser.setEmail(newUser.getEmail());
     oldUser.setContactNum(newUser.getContactNum())
}`

Comment: Exactly i thought same, it should be  userService.save(user);

Comment: @AnudeepGade or that. I prefer to update existing entity with new data.

Comment: I thought `userService.save(user3)` can do update also with new values. How can I do update @arados ?

Comment: I usually create method for update. `private void update(oldEntity, newEntity) { oldEntity.setSomething(newEntity.getSomething())}`

Comment: I have updated my answer more code. I hope it helps.